# No OpenSSL sign-file signing_key.pem leads to error while loading kernel modules

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, kernel, kernel-module

I am having problems while loading/installing a kernel module. The kernel module builds successfully, but whenever I try to make module_install, the kernel seems to fail to load. It leaves the below error message :-

```
At main.c:158:
    - SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
    - SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178 sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
    DEPMOD 4.10.0-20-generic
```

I have read about this problem and realized that the kernel has now started loading only properly signed modules. I find that the kernel source directory `/usr/src/<linux version>/certs` in my system does not have the `signing_key.pem` private key file because of which I see this error.

What should I do ? Can I manually generate a `signing_key.pem` file and use it further ? What would be some good methods to do so ? Will generating a private key/certificate file using `openssl.cnf` help me in this regard ? Or should I avoid using signed modules at all and try loading the modules as it is without any verification ?

I am using **Ubuntu 17.04 with kernel 4.10.0-20-generic**.

Comment: I too am experiencing this. Even though I seem to compile everything fine, the kernel driver never gets loaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your linux kernel root folder that you're compiling go to the certs folder and run:

```
openssl req -new -nodes -utf8 -sha512 -days 36500 -batch -x509 -config x509.genkey -outform DER -out signing_key.x509 -keyout signing_key.pem
```

Where x509.genkey is a file with the contents:

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 4096
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
prompt = no
string_mask = utf8only
x509_extensions = myexts

[ req_distinguished_name ]
CN = Modules

[ myexts ]
basicConstraints=critical,CA:FALSE
keyUsage=digitalSignature
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid
```

Refer to: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Signed_kernel_module_support

Option 2, is disable automated signing of modules in the config `make menuconfig` or `make xconfig`

Answer (score 4):

Based on [cryptoboy's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1322832/1413203):

1. Create x509.genkey file

   ```bash
   echo -e "[ req ] \n\
   default_bits = 4096 \n\
   distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name \n\
   prompt = no \n\
   x509_extensions = myexts \n\

   [ req_distinguished_name ] \n\
   CN = Modules \n\
   \n\
   [ myexts ] \n\
   basicConstraints=critical,CA:FALSE \n\
   keyUsage=digitalSignature \n\
   subjectKeyIdentifier=hash \n\
   authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid" > x509.genkey
   ```
2. Run:

   ```
   openssl req -new -nodes -utf8 -sha512 -days 36500 -batch -x509 -config x509.genkey -outform DER -out signing_key.x509 -keyout signing_key.pem
   ```
3. Move key files to desired folder, for example:

   ```
   mv signing_key.pem signing_key.x509 `find /usr/src/*-generic/certs`
   ```

Answer (score 0):

this command works for me, on Manjaro Linux, 2023:

https://github.com/webcamoid/akvcam/issues/15#issuecomment-612657792

> Some people reported that running `sudo depmod -a` may fix the problem.